# How to move scroll Y axis regardless of device height in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I make 1 component which has 4 sections in vertical.

And if I click menu located on top I want to make scroll move to each section.

For example,

- click menu 1 -> section 1
- click menu 2 -> section 2
- click menu 3 -> section 3

For this, I get Y value of each section by `useScroll` of framer-motion.

And if I click certain menu, I make `window.location` move to that Y value.

But the problem is if I look this homepage on cell phone, not desktop, since device height changes, sections' Y value also changes.

So even if it moves to Y value of section 2 of device 1, in device2, scroll points different section.

So How to make this function regardless of different device height?

I also tried to use `Route path` as separating each section by having different route.

But I couldn't differentiate component's route path in one page.

```
  const { scrollY } = useScroll();
  const [ychange, setYchange] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    scrollY.onChange(() => {
      
      setYchange(scrollY.get());
      
    });
  }, [scrollY]);

<NavItem
          onClick={() => {
            navigate("/");
            setTimeout(() => {
              window.scrollTo({ top: 5235, behavior: "smooth" });
            });
          }}
        >
          <AppText page={page} ychange={ychange} location={location}>
            앱 소개
          </AppText>
          {page === "app" ||
          (location === "/" && ychange >= 5234 && ychange < 10336) ? (
            <NavBottom />
          ) : null}
        </NavItem>
```

Comment: Can you share a minimal reproducible example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `element.scrollIntoView()` might be a good fit if this is the use case:

> - click menu 1 -> section 1
> - click menu 2 -> section 2
> - click menu 3 -> section 3

A possible implement is to make a reference for each `section` to be scrolled to with `useRef`, and call `scrollIntoView()` on the referenced element.

[More about `element.scrollIntoView()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)

Optional: an offset area from the top of the element when scrolled to can be specified with `scroll-margin-top` in styles.

[More about `scroll-margin-top`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-margin-top)

Here is a basic example of this implemented. It runs in the snippet for convenience and works better when viewing in full page.

Not sure if this approach would work well in the actual project since posted code is partial, but hope this could still help as a reference.

```js
const { useRef } = React;

const App = () => {
  const sectionsRef = useRef([]);

  const handleScrollTo = (index) => {
    if (!sectionsRef.current[index]) return;
    sectionsRef.current[index].scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <nav>
        {[1, 2, 3, 4].map((item, index) => (
          <button key={item} onClick={()=>handleScrollTo(index)}>{`Section ${item}`}</button>
        ))}
      </nav>
      {[1, 2, 3, 4].map((item, index) => (
        <section key={item} ref={(element) => (sectionsRef.current[index] = element)}>
          <h3>{`This is section ${item}`}</h3>
        </section>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <App />
);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav,
section,
button {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

nav {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  padding: 6px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: lightpink;
  gap: 12px;
}

button {
  padding: 6px;
}

section {
  scroll-margin-top: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

section:nth-of-type(1) {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

section:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

section:nth-of-type(3) {
  background-color: purple;
}

section:nth-of-type(4) {
  background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have same idea but using nodes to call `scrollIntoView`, not using ref.